# Custom google analytics for multiple JS

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

Requirement:
In website i have 4 JS popup.

When page load first popup will open. 
User can click next so first popup hide and next will show.

User can close any popup.

So user can navigate 4 pop ups by presssing next and close inbetween.

So i want to track when user press next button or close button at which popup with **GOOGLE ANALYTICS**.

How can i do that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: @SilentTremor Thanks!